# Join non-digit character strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {"20","ab","Cd","10","E"}
```

in which I would like to join adjacent elements if they are letters and not digits, to give:

```
res = {"20","abCd","10","E"}
```

Again thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
StringJoin /@ SplitBy[lis, LetterQ]
```

**Edit**

That doesn't work if there are adjacent non-letter strings. Try this instead:

```
If[AllTrue[#, LetterQ], StringJoin[#], Splice[#]] & /@ SplitBy[lis, LetterQ]
```

Another option:

```
Flatten[SequenceSplit[lis, {str__?LetterQ} :> StringJoin[str]]]
```

Comment: Works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
lis = {"20", "ab", "Cd", "10", "E"}
```

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {s__String?(StringFreeQ[DigitCharacter])} .. :> 
  StringJoin@s]
```

> `{"20", "abCd", "10", "E"}`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {"20", "ab", "Cd", "bb", "10", "33", "E", "F"};
```

Using `ReplaceRepeated`

```
list //. {a___, b_?LetterQ, c_?LetterQ, d___} :> {a, StringJoin[b, c],d}
```

{"20", "abCdbb", "10", "33", "EF"}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"20", "ab", "Cd", "bb", "10", "33", "E", "F"};
```

---

Grabbing the @eldo's list and using `ReplacePart` and `DeleteElements`:

```
p = Split[Position[list, s_String /; LetterQ[s]], #2[[1]] - #1[[1]] == 1 &];

f = DeleteElements[ReplacePart[list, Thread[p -> #]], Length /@ p - 1 -> #] &;

f@Map[StringJoin, Extract[list, List@*Span @@@ MinMax /@ p]]
```

> `{"20", "abCdbb", "10", "33", "EF"}`